# How to query for records with associations that either don't exist or all have non-null value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a tasks table in Postgres is 9.4.7 like this:

```
goal_id | expires_at
1       | null  
1       | 2017-05-3  
2       | null
3       | 2017-05-3
```

And a goals table like this:

```
id
1   
2
3
4
```

I want to be able to return all goals that do not have associated tasks, and goals whose associated tasks are all expired (`expires_at` isn't null). Basically, I need to return goals with id 3 and 4.

So far I need 2 queries, since `array_agg` returns a null value if there are no associated tasks in the `LEFT JOIN` One for the goals with tasks, and one for the goals without tasks.

```
SELECT goals.id
FROM goals
JOIN tasks
  ON tasks.goal_id = goals.id
GROUP BY 1
  HAVING TRUE = ALL(SELECT unnest(array_agg(tasks.expires_at)) IS NOT NULL)

SELECT goals.id
FROM goals
LEFT JOIN tasks
  ON tasks.goal_id = goals.id
WHERE tasks.id IS NULL
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this with a simple `not exists` query:

```
select g.*
from goals g
where not exists (select 1
                  from tasks t
                  where t.goal_id = g.id and
                        t.expired_at is null
                 );
```

Comment: And the result of your query is `2,4`... It should be  `... t.expired_at is null ...` to meet the "_goals whose associated tasks are **all** expired_" requirement.